# Is first-day-of-week language-based or country-based on JVM?

Tags: java, calendar, jvm

One can obtain the first day of week on JVM by calling `Calendar.getInstance(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek()`. Yet, is this information language-based, or country-based?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out, this is JDK version-dependent. JDK8 returns first day of week based on language, so it returns `SUNDAY` for `"en_FI"` `"en_US"` and `MONDAY` for `"fi_FI"` and `"fi_US"`.

However, JDK9 switched to the CLDR system which (more logically) uses country. So, JDK9 will return `MONDAY` both for `"en_FI"` and `"fi_FI"` locales, and will return `SUNDAY` for `"fi_US"` and `"en_US"`.

See [JEP 252](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) for more details.

Also, quoting from [JDK-8203280](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203280):

> To add an explanation to this behavior, the CLDR implementation is correct, i.e., the first day of week should be defined by the region, not by the language.

Comment: It's not really true that it's "based on language". It's just based on *different data* between Java 8 and 9.

Comment: Also, I think linking to a bug is somewhat misleading given that it's actually not a bug.

Comment: I agree; however the bug answers the question in a more clear way. Let me rephrase the answer.

Comment: You can get the behaviour you want. E.g., you may set the system property `java.locale.providers` to `CLDR,COMPAT` in Java 8 to give priority to CLDR locale data. Or to `COMPAT,CLDR` in Java 9 to give priority to the Java 8 compatible data over CLDR.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it is country-based: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()

> Gets what the first day of the week is; e.g., SUNDAY in the U.S.,
>   MONDAY in France.

Comment: That's the problem - it isn't :( Try running `Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("fi", "US")).getFirstDayOfWeek()` on OpenJDK8 - it will return MONDAY even though the country is US. On JDK8, this is language-based. Could it be that Oracle JVM works in a different way?